# Singleton EJB , JPA Concurrent Access

Tags: jpa, singleton, ejb

I have a MDB which calls Singleton EJB for maintaining hourlyTotals using JPA. I am getting StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction

Entity Bean Code

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "hour_db")
public class HourlyTotalEntity {
    @Id
    private Date transactionTime;

    @Column(name="success_count")
    private long  successCount;

    @Version int version;


    public Date getTransactionTime() {
        return transactionTime;
    }

    public void setTransactionTime(Date transactionTime) {
        this.transactionTime = transactionTime;
    }

    public void setSuccessCount(long successCount)
    {
        this.successCount = successCount;
    }
    public long getSuccessCount()
    {
        return successCount;
    }

    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
}
```

EJB Code

```
@Singleton
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER)
@Lock(LockType.READ)
public class HourlyTotalEJB {
    @PersistenceContext (unitName="DashboardJPA")
    private EntityManager em;

    public void create(Date transactionTime) throws Exception
    {
        transactionTime = trim(transactionTime);
        HourlyTotalEntity entity = em.find(HourlyTotalEntity.class, transactionTime,LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT);
        if(entity == null)
        {
            entity = new HourlyTotalEntity();
            entity.setTransactionTime(transaction);
            entity.setSuccessCount(0);
        }

        entity.setAuthSuccessCount(entity.getAuthSuccessCount() + 1);
        em.persist(entity);
        em.flush();
        em.clear();
    }

    private Date trim(Date date) 
    {
         Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
         calendar.setTime(date);
         calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
         calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
         calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
         return calendar.getTime();
    }
}
```

The MDB call the  create(transactionTime) on onMessage(Message message) method. During high volume of transcations the method create(transcationTime) will be called concurrently by MDBs and results in StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction

How to resolve the above issue?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a [read lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/LockType.html), this permits multiple threads to call the method simultaneously.  Since the `create` method is not read-only, you should use a write lock instead.